# Gitlab stop working after instal iRedMail

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I have a little problem.
I have VPS with debian 8. I have installed on it apache2 serwer and gitlab ce with default settings.

My serwer work on port 80 and my gitlab worked on 81 ( external_url ).

Everything stop working when i installed iRedMail.
Now I have uninstalled iRedMail but gitlab doesn't work.

After use command "gitlab-ctl restart" all packages are ok (gitlab-workhouse, logrotate, nginx, postgresql, redis, sidekiq, unicorn), but If i try to open site with gitlab, I have got error the page timeout.

What and how should check to solve this problem?

I have to add that I hace checked listen ports and nginx are in this list.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4534/nginx
```

---------- EDIT

"stop working" = after I type "external_url" (which worked) I got "Connection timed out".

I have checked logs in /var/log/gitlab for 
gitlab-rails, gitlab-shell, gitlab-workhorse, nginx etc.

In gitlab-rails folder I found files : production.log (clear) and sidekiq.log. There are many of ERRORS ( I paste 2 first line, next are similar ):

```
2015-12-14_14:57:44.37657 2015-12-14T14:57:44.376Z 14796 TID-daijk ERROR: Error fetching message: No such file or directory - connect(2) for /var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.socket
2015-12-14_14:57:44.37672 2015-12-14T14:57:44.376Z 14796 TID-daijk ERROR: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:180:in `connect_nonblock'
```

I Have to add that my apache server works fine on :80.

Comment: What do you mean with "stop working"? No access, gateway errors? Please read you log files for nginx, apache2, gitlab-rails (production), unicorn and gitlab-workhorse. Because of gitlab-omnibus' decentral concept it is hard to solve proxy problems, so your log files are really important.

Comment: I have checked it. Look at my first post.